# Keyword highlighting in Notepad++ UDL

Tags: notepad++, udl

I am trying to create a User-Defined Language Syntax Highlighting Style in Notepad++ that would allow me to use wildcard chars or some other mechanism to detect keywords. For example, in the Language I am using, there are many system functions that start with the letter `f` (lower-case, mandatory). ALL function name declarations must end with `$` like this:

```
fGetCurrentState$ (listParams) {Code}
```

Also, user-created functions can be added, as long as they follow the same rules:

```
fMyFunction$ (listParams) {Code}
```

I know I can exhaustively add all System function names to the Keywords list and highlight the line, but this is unsustainable and leaves all user functions out. So, finally, my question (thanks for reading this far):

Is it possible to define smart highlighting? What I want to tell Notepad++ is this: 'Highlight any word that STARTS with `f` and ENDS with `$` AND `f` MUST be the first character in the line.

Comment: Does the highlighting have to be automatic (that is, applied as you type) or do you also accept marking all such keywords on request? The latter is easy, find regex `^f[^\s]+\$`, without closing the Find dialog go to the Mark tab, and select "Mark all". If instead you want the former, I don't think it's possible, but I rarely (if ever) use UDLs so maybe there's something I don't know.

Comment: Yeah, the whole point of the User-Defined Language Syntax Highlighting is that it does it in real time, as you type. It makes Notepad++ feel like an IDE.

Comment: Ok, but I don't think it's possible. Why did you rollback the edit anyway? It was a good one!